# How to insert double quoted string value in database using codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know codeigniter automatically escape characters to prevent possible sql injections. But how would I able to store string value in the database with double quotes on it. Is this possible? Or is there a function or condition that can ignore double quotes and still store it in the database using codeigniter active records? I have tried to store a double quoted value in the database but it fails to store the value. E.g. I want to store this value "Computer Course" in the database using the variable `$course_desc` but the description field in my database stores nothing.How would I able to do this? Here is my model active record code for inserting values:

Model:

```
public function insert_file($filename,$course_name,$course_desc,$tennant_email,$is_public,$concat_url)
{
  $data = array(
     'course_id'     => '',
     'tennant_id'    => $tennant_email,
     'display_public'=> $is_public,
     'course_name'   => $course_name,
     'course_desc'   => $course_desc,
     'private_url'   => $concat_url,
     'filename'      => $filename

              );

        $this->db->insert('courses', $data);
         return true;
  }
```

Comment: Queries with AR are automatically escaped so quotes shouldn't be a problem. If you var_dump($data) the value is enclosed by quotes?

Comment: Given your sample data this should work as is. what does $this->db->insert('courses', $data); return? Try putting this as the next line : echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: please post your query.If you use double quotes in description then it should work.No problem with that.

Comment: Yeah., AR automatically escaped characters. But the problem is whenever I want to save the $course_desc variable that is suppose to have a string value with double quotes on it, it wouldn't be saved. I want to save a string value for the $course_desc with double quotes around it when it is actually saved on the database in my phpmyadmin but it never been stored there.

Comment: E.g. "I want to save this string including the quotes around this in the database".  Variable $course_desc is the variable assigned to store this value including the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the variable like this below,

```
$data = array( 'course_desc'   => '"'.$course_desc.'"' )
```

Kindly let me know whether this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a problem on inserting data with double quotes("), i suggest to you to try using replace. For example:

```
$data = array(
     'course_id'     => '',
     'tennant_id'    => $tennant_email,
     'display_public'=> $is_public,
     'course_name'   => $course_name,
     'course_desc'   => str_replace('"','xxxxx',$course_desc)),
     'private_url'   => $concat_url,
     'filename'      => $filename

              );

        $this->db->insert('courses', $data);
```

and vice versa when selecting / getting on it in the database.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '\'

```
$data = array(

    'course_desc'   => "\"$course_desc\""

}
```